# What is the default calendar program?

Tags: default, calendar

I've noticed that Ubuntu doesn't come with a default calendar program... why not?

Comment: Which version are you asking about? 11.04 and back was evolution, but as of 11.10 and making Thunderbird default over evolution...I don't think there is one.

Comment: I'm talking about since Thunderbird was made the default e-mail program Ubuntu has been limping along without a default calendar program. Evolution can't be considered the default program because it's not even installed in the default install of the OS. What is a person (noob) installing 12.04 for the first time going to think especially if their skill level is low?

Comment: You have a great point. Eek... I had the feeling from the get-go that the transition from Evolution to Thunderbird wasn't a smart idea....

Comment: Please don't get me wrong, I'm just trying to be constructive cause I think this (our) OS has a great future and I think a good (integrated) calendar program is a must if we are trying to push 12.04 as a LTS for business use.

Comment: I agree with you 100%. OSX has a standard calendar application that integrates with everything, Windows does not..and currently Ubuntu doesn't either. Please, please let's not let OSX be the leader in this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer here...[View appointments in your calendar](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-help/clock-calendar.html), within the Ubuntu 'Help' Documentation!

Answer (score 3):

Go to >> **System settings**>>Details  >>Default Application [image]

Comment: everytime try to improve your answer. If your answer consists of the image then what you are trying to say will be more clear.+1 for the good answer.

Comment: For me in 14.04, it says that gedit is my calendar. :-(

Answer (score 3):

For a calender in the sense of a list of days grouped by weeks, months and years,
there are [`cal`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/cal.1.html) and `ncal` (same man page);

At 2014-10-07:

```
$ cal
    October 2014      
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  
          1  2  3  4  
 5  6 [7] 8  9 10 11  
12 13 14 15 16 17 18  
19 20 21 22 23 24 25  
26 27 28 29 30 31
```

(The `[7]` is shown inverted.)
To see more months, Use `-A n` or `-B n` to show n month after or before, `-y` for the whole year, or `-3` for the current month with one month before and after:

```
$ cal -3      
   September 2014         October 2014         November 2014      
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  
    1  2  3  4  5  6            1  2  3  4                     1  
 7  8  9 10 11 12 13   5  6 [7] 8  9 10 11   2  3  4  5  6  7  8  
14 15 16 17 18 19 20  12 13 14 15 16 17 18   9 10 11 12 13 14 15  
21 22 23 24 25 26 27  19 20 21 22 23 24 25  16 17 18 19 20 21 22  
28 29 30              26 27 28 29 30 31     23 24 25 26 27 28 29  
                                            30
```

Use `ncal` if you need the calendar week, the index of the week in the year; It has a different layout also:

```
$ ncal -w      
    October 2014      
Su     5 12 19 26   
Mo     6 13 20 27   
Tu    [7]14 21 28   
We  1  8 15 22 29   
Th  2  9 16 23 30   
Fr  3 10 17 24 31   
Sa  4 11 18 25      
   40 41 42 43 44
```

Comment: Mere dates can be viewed using the Date/Time applet in the tray. A calendar in the sense of the question has more to do with events, appointments, etc. than knowing whether the 23rd is a Thursday or a Friday.

Comment: Right, implied by the "program" in "calendar program". I added a differentiation.

Answer (score 2):

it doesn't? if there isn't one you can easily install any number of calender application,
This one for unity, 
http://news.softpedia.com/news/Introducing-Ubuntu-Calendar-Lens-for-Unity-243676.shtml
here is a list best of list, http://www.ekoob.com/best-calendar-applications-for-ubuntu-10427/

Answer (score 2):

Thunderbird does have calendaring, but it is in a separate extension called Lightning, you can install it from the software centre or

```
sudo apt-get install xul-ext-lightning
```

maybe we should think about installing this by default.

Comment: That would be a good start because it's a little difficult for the new user to find, and if they could integrate it with the Gnome desktop calendar would help to make it more new user friendly.

Answer (score 1):

Evolution is the default calendar program.

To test it out, click on the statusbar clock, then on the current date.

Comment: As mentioned above by Ryan McClure, this is true only for Ubuntu 11.04 and earlier. I think the OP wants to know why a calendar application doesn't come installed by default in 11.10 and later.

Comment: Oh.. I upgraded to 11.10, so Evolution was already set-up as the default calendar program, I guess. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 16.04 has a calendar that you can view just by clicking on the time and date in the top right-hand corner of the screen:

[image: Screenshot]

If you install GNOME Calendar (`sudo apt install gnome-calendar`), you can create events, and they will appear in this widget.